# Can't open django admin from my live website in cPanel [too many redirects]

Tags: django, database, sqlite, cpanel, admin

I am trying to open https://mywebsite.org/admin but it's responsing **"This page isn’t working, mywebsite.org redirected you too many times. Try deleting your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS."**

everything is working perfect in my local server. I'm facing this only on the live server in cPanel. All other tasks are working fine without the admin page.

I am stuck for last 2 days on the same issue. I have tried most of the  solutions available online .

- ensured static files
- transfered collect_static's admin folder to the public_html folder of cPanel
- checked all my urls
- used ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/' in the settings.py
- used whitenoise

I am using deafult sqlite3 database of django. is that the issue?

Comment: Ensure the url ends with a backslash. It may be that https/http is not handled correctly. What is the "location" header of the redirect? (check you browser dev network panel)

Comment: @erny I've checked with ending urls.
here is the location header detail:
Request URL: https://mywebsite.org/admin/login?next=/admin/login%3Fnext%3D/admin/login%253Fnext%253D/admin/login%25253Fnext%25253D/admin/login%2525253Fnext%2525253D/admin/login%252525253Fnext%252525253D/admin/login%25252525253Fnext%25252525253D/admin/login%2525252525253Fnext%2525252525253D/admin/login%252525252525253Fnext%252525252525253D/admin/

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: I'm not familiar with deploying django trough cPanel. I think there'll be some other website in front of django like nginx or apache. Have you set "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL" in settings? Your link has a recurrent 'next' parameter again to /admin/login/. Could it be that the session cookie is not sent to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had problem with my Hosting account. I talked to the owner and the managing team, and they solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).